# html graphs from database

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

General Question.

Hi guys,

Before I go on any further this is a seeking information rather than a research a code solution.

I am currently writing a report at the moment and I need a small bit of help with future development of a particular piece of business activity.

The current solution is that that data is mined from a database and then is placed into an Excel spread sheet and then emailed to the people who need it.

What I'd like to do is to remove going through Excel entirely and then to publish online so that the reader can see the data represented in graphs and data tables. Is this possible? and if so which technologies should I start looking to learn?

Keith

Comment: I don't mean to sound blunt, but did you even bother to Google this? Plenty of JavaScript and PHP libraries for making graphs easily. For example: https://developers.google.com/chart/ and http://jpgraph.net/

Comment: Apologies for asking the question so poorly. The reason why I asked this as an open ended question was I was aware that it is possible through the likes of general php and javascript but I was trying to find out if there was statistical specific technologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jqplot](http://www.jqplot.com) is also an good option it contains many facilities like every device compatibility , zooming, tooltip and its open source too